# Getting the Lagrangian from the action in curved spacetime

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, action, conventions, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Suppose I have this action:

$$ S = \int \mathrm d^4 x\sqrt{-g}\times \text{something}$$

where $g$ is the determinant of the metric.

Should I take the Lagrangian to be:

$$ \mathcal L = \sqrt{-g} \times \text{something} $$

or:

$$ \mathcal L = \text{something}$$

instead? Yes, this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, in a sense, just semantics but I'd say the natural choice is $\mathcal{L}=\sqrt{-g}\times \text{something}$. If you take this definition, the general form of the equations of motion is the same as when doing QFT in Minkowski, with the appropriate generalizations to account for curvature. Furthermore, I think it is standard practice to define the action by
$$S\equiv \int dt L=\int d^4x \mathcal{L}$$
This form is also preserved when the convention I propose is accepted.

Answer (score 3):

The natural choice is actually $\mathcal{L}=\text{something}$, the reason being is that the $\sqrt{-g}$ term is naturally paired with the volume form $d^4x$.

Even before considering curved spacetime, consider non Cartesian coordinates.  For example [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)
$$ dt\,dx\,dy\,dz = r^2 \sin\theta\ dt\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$$

Where does that term $r^2 \sin\theta$ come from?  That is the [determinant of the Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of the change of coordinates.  This is the role $\sqrt{-g}$ plays, without which the volume form would not be invariant to coordinate changes.

If you separated it the other way, neither the Lagrangian density nor the volume form would be Lorentz invariant.  So it makes much more sense to keep the $\sqrt{-g}$ with the integration, and keep $\mathcal{L}$ just a Lagrangian density.

Comment: I agree with @PhysStudent, the natural choice is indeed $\mathcal{L} = \text{something}$. The $\sqrt{-g} dx^{0} \wedge dx^{1} \cdots$ part that appears in the $\mathit{action}$ is the volume form on the manifold. By definition we have that the action is taken as the integral over the space (say $\Omega$) where the Lagrangian density is defined:

$\mathcal{S} := \int_{\Omega} \mathcal{L} = \int d^{4} \boldsymbol{x} \sqrt{-g} \mathcal{L}$.

Comment: The problem with the definition $\mathcal{L} = \sqrt{-g} \times \cdots$ is that it only works for Lorentzian manifolds. If you wanted to then work on a Riemannian space (for whatever reason) your definition is no longer valid. If you remove any trace of the $\sqrt{-g}$ from the Lagrangian and say that it arises in the volume form within the action then no inconsistency can ever arise.

Comment: I agree with your points, but to derive the Euler-Lagrange equations, we normally take $\mathcal{L}=\sqrt{|g|} \times \dots$?

Comment: If you forget the $\sqrt{-g}$ term in cosmology, your matter will not dilute etc. Working on a curved and dynamical background, it would be a rudimentary error to omit the $\sqrt{-g}$ term.

Comment: Plus, do notice that only with the $\sqrt{-g}$ term the Lagrangian is truly a [density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_on_a_manifold).

Comment: @JamalS To derive the Euler-Lagrange equations, we start with the action, as it comes from the stationary action principle.  So I'm not sure why you think a $\sqrt{-g}$ is being omitted.

Comment: @Void If you are saying the $\sqrt{-g}$ is needed to have the Lagrangian transform like a scalar density, then are you saying $d^4x$ transforms fine without the g factor?  It seems like the spherical coordinate argument above (or just from the definition Arthur uses) disagrees with that.

Comment: @PhysStudent Well, then in your Euler-Lagrange equations you would not have $\mathcal{L}$ but $\mathcal{L} \sqrt{-g}$ due to the $\partial_{x^\mu}$ terms ($\delta \phi_{,\mu}$ variations and the per partes). The Lagrangian density should be the thing appearing in the Lagrange equations, should it not? The whole argumentation with volume forms is flawed when it comes to non-orientable manifolds - we are truly talking about *densities* not volume forms here. $d^4 x$ is then just a [density of a different weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density).

Comment: @Void Okay maybe this is just a notation convention then, because I have never seen the $\sqrt{-g}$ subsumed into the Lagrangian density.  Instead it is left paired with the volume term, like with the [Einstein-Hilbert Action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action#Cosmological_constant)

Comment: @John In supergravity via superspace formalism, chiral density (which includes $\sqrt{-g}$ as the lowest component) is usually taken into the Lagrangian density.